# Convert pandas Series to dict with type conversion?

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a file containing miscellaneous parameters, stored as csv. I'm loading it into Python using `pandas.read_csv`, which very conveniently returns a `DataFrame` with one column. But I don't need any of the fancy `pandas` features, so I immediately convert my data to a `dict`.

My next problem is that the parameters all have different types: some are integers, some may be floats, and some are strings. `pandas` usually loads them with `dtype=object`, and they go into the `dict` as strings. (Except sometimes they're all numeric, so I get a numeric `dtype` right away.) I wrote a simple function that attempts to identify numeric types and convert them appropriately.

```py
header = {key: typecast(value)
          for (key, value) in dict(header['Value']).items()}

def typecast(value):
    """Convert a string to a numeric type if possible

    >>> def cast_with_type(s):
    ...     return (result := typecast(s), type(result))
    >>> cast_with_type(123)
    (123, <class 'int'>)
    >>> cast_with_type('foo')
    ('foo', <class 'str'>)
    >>> cast_with_type('123')
    (123, <class 'int'>)
    >>> cast_with_type('123.4')
    (123.4, <class 'float'>)
    """
    try:
        if '.' in value:
            return float(value)
        else:
            return int(value)
    except TypeError:
        return value
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

Is there a built-in feature that does this better than what I already have?

Comment: Reading into pandas just to convert to dict seems like a lot of overhead, what about the [csv.DictReader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) module?

Comment: `csv.DictReader()` doesn't do the type conversion (I just checked). It's also overkill in its own way because I only have one column of values. I'm not worried about runtime overhead, because I load this file along with some other, much larger files.

Comment: Or storing the file as JSON?

Comment: JSON is an interesting idea, though too much overhead (these files are often edited and viewed manually by humans, too). TOML could work, though. The only problem, at this point, is that I already have a few dozen of these files that would need to be converted. Not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it you want to convert any dtype into a numeric dtype and then make it into a dictionary. For this you can use the astype() method
(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert it into the required dtype and then convert your dataframe to a dictionary.

```
df = df.astype(float)
my_dict = df.to_dict()
```

Your `dict` can be oriented in anyway you want just refer https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: Won't `astype(float)` fail when given a mixture of numeric and alphanumeric values?